# Deleting variables with identical observations

Tags: stata

I would like to delete all variables of a dataset, in which all observations have the same value (`-94`).

My approach is the following:

```
local abc *all variables of the dataset*

tostring `abc', replace force

foreach var of local abc {
    replace `abc' = "" if `abc' == "-94"
}
```

However, I get a Type Mismatch error and cannot continue with the `dropmiss` command.

My dataset has `1900` variables but only `106` Observations. The variables are both, string and numerical, hence I had to run the `tostring` command in the beginning.

Data example (only includes variables to be dorpped):

```
clear
input str7(ELi014c ELi014d) long(ELi012a ELi012b ELi012c ELi012d) str7 ELi008a
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
"-94" "-94" -94 -94 -94 -94 "-94"
end
```

Comment: See https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1515914-deleting-variables-with-the-same-values for more on why the code here is wrong or ill-advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the toy example below:

```
clear
set obs 10

generate v1 = -94 // numeric

forvalues i = 2 / 4 {
    generate v`i' = rnormal() // numeric
}

generate v5 = "-94" // string

list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |  v1          v2          v3          v4    v5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | -94    .1810702    .1617331   -.0910539   -94 |
  2. | -94   -2.472578     .884746   -.5641506   -94 |
  3. | -94   -1.259646   -.9369262    .0942772   -94 |
  4. | -94    .2986405    .2054719    -1.25441   -94 |
  5. | -94    .4703567    1.868845    .0574179   -94 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  6. | -94   -.5504516    .3403896   -1.720799   -94 |
  7. | -94   -1.504979    .0951505   -.4002379   -94 |
  8. | -94   -.6522541    1.021817   -2.524902   -94 |
  9. | -94    .9978508     -1.4657   -.5643548   -94 |
 10. | -94    .2728079    -.177151     1.16664   -94 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

You can then find the variables of interest as follows:

```
destring *, replace

ds

foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
    quietly summarize `var'
    if `r(min)' == `r(max)' drop `var'
}

list

     +-----------------------------------+
     |        v2          v3          v4 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  .1810702    .1617331   -.0910539 |
  2. | -2.472578     .884746   -.5641506 |
  3. | -1.259646   -.9369262    .0942772 |
  4. |  .2986405    .2054719    -1.25441 |
  5. |  .4703567    1.868845    .0574179 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  6. | -.5504516    .3403896   -1.720799 |
  7. | -1.504979    .0951505   -.4002379 |
  8. | -.6522541    1.021817   -2.524902 |
  9. |  .9978508     -1.4657   -.5643548 |
 10. |  .2728079    -.177151     1.16664 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Here is another way of doing this without mass conversion of variable types or external commands:

```
ds

foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
    capture assert `var' == `var'[1]
    if !_rc drop `var'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is sufficient to illustrate the use of `findname` from the *Stata Journal*. There is no need to convert all the data to string, or any such mass conversion.

```
clear
input str7(ELi014c ELi014d) long(ELi012a ELi012b) foo 
"-94" "-94" -94 -94  1
"-94" "-94" -94 -94  2
"-94" "-94" -94 -94  3
"-94" "-94" -94 -94  4
"-94" "-94" -94 -94  5
end 

findname, all(@ == -94) local(bad1) 
findname, all(@ == "-94") local(bad2) 

drop `bad1' `bad2' 

list 

     +-----+
     | foo |
     |-----|
  1. |   1 |
  2. |   2 |
  3. |   3 |
  4. |   4 |
  5. |   5 |
     |-----|
```